# How can I auto-case key names when saving to Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object:

```
{ SKU: 'TR1234',
  Description: 'Item 1',
  UoM: 'each',
  client_id: '531382e3005fe0c926bd3957',
  Meta: { Test: 'test1', Image: 'http://www.aol.com' } }
```

I'm trying to save it given my schema:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
  sku: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  company_id: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Client',
  },
  createdOn: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updatedOn: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
}, {versionKey: false});
```

But it doesn't save and I assume it's because of the capitalized key names. However, those are dynamically generated from a CSV which is parsed with https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson

Ideas?

Comment: It looks like that CSV tool lets you provide your own customized parser where you could do this sort of field renaming.

Comment: How would I do something like this?

Comment: There was the Parser as mentioned. The documentation is on the Github page. If that is not clear for you not work out, edit with this extra information. What does your CSV file look like and which fields are mapping to which in your schema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also just use a setter in your mongoose schema, like that:

```
function toLower (v) {
    return v.toLowerCase();
}

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, set: toLower } 
});
```

Just apply it to your fields.

```
There is also one more approach, just:
email   : { type: String, lowercase: true }
```

**Update for keys:**
If you would like to change keys, you should the approach likes 'ecdeveloper' mentioned below. My answer was for values, so it makes sense to give this reputation to 'ecdeveloper'. Sorry for confusing.

Here is one more approach without creating a new object:

```
Object.prototype.keysToUpper = function () {
    var k;
    for (k in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(k))
            this[k.toLowerCase()] = this[k];
            delete this[k];    
    }
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Setter will apply on the value. Shamoon needs actually to lower case the key names, not the values.

Comment: Yeap, sorry for that, your answer is correct with modifying keys via a loop. Because there is no stuff in mongodb to update keys.

Answer (score 6):

What about calling toLowerCase() on each key from your object, and build a new object with lower case keys?

```
// Assumy your object name is obj
var newObj = {}; 
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    newObj[key.toLowerCase()] = obj[key];
});

// Here you can save your newObj
```

Comment: Mongoose expects the keys to line up, and overriding it to allow mixed case keys would be quite tedious. If you can't change the parser, this would work.